# delay http response coming back to tomcat server for testing

Tags: java, http, proxy, tomcat7, fiddler

So I have a application running on tomcat application server(A) that sends a http request to another server(B). I would like to test behaviour for when there is a delay in the response coming back from server b. What would be the best way to test this without changing the code base?

Is fiddler2 a  option if so could you tell me how this would be set up? Are there any other recommended tools?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could use Fiddler for this; just use a ***delay** rule in the AutoResponder.

To use Fiddler, you'd put it on the server (A) and configure Tomcat to use it (127.0.0.1:8888) as its proxy.